# Why are the coordinates of my turtle and another object not the same even though they are in the same spot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm having trouble with my while loop not returning false when the snake's head/turtle is at the same coordinates as the apple. I've tried to troubleshoot by printing out the values, the values are the same with the turtle position having an extra zero on the end ex: the apple has an output of (160.0, 160.0) and the turtle has an output of (160.00, 160.00). When the snake head/turtle and the the apple are at the same positions the output of ***snake.pos() != fruit*** is still true; snake.pos() should equal fruit and end the while loop.

```
#imports
import turtle
import random
import keyboard
import time
#apple
apple = turtle
a = 455.00
b = 455.00 - 65.00
c = 455.00 - 65.00 * 2.00
d = 455.00 - 65.00 * 3.00
e = 455.00 - 65.00 * 4.00
f = 455.00 - 65.00 * 5.00
g = 455.00 - 65.00 * 6.00
h = 455.00 - 65.00 * 7.00
i = 455.00 - 65.00* 8.00
j = 455.00 - 65.00 * 9.00
k = 455.00 - 65.00 * 10.00
l = 455.00 - 65.00 * 11.00
m = 455.00 - 65.00 * 12.00
n = 455.00 - 65.00 * 13.00
o = 455.00 - 65.00 * 14.00
poll1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]
poll2 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n]
x = random.choice(poll1)
y = random.choice(poll2)
print(x)
print(y)
apple.shape("square")
apple.turtlesize(stretch_wid=3, stretch_len=3, outline=3)
apple.tracer(n=1, delay=0)
apple.penup()
apple.colormode(255)
apple.pencolor(255, 0, 0)
apple.fillcolor(255, 0, 0)
apple.goto(x, y)
apple.forward(30)
apple.pendown()
fruit = x,y
apple.begin_fill()
apple.right(90)
apple.forward(30)
for p in range(0, 3):
    apple.right(90)
    apple.forward(60)
apple.right(90)
apple.forward(30)
apple.end_fill()
apple.pencolor(0, 0, 0)
apple.fillcolor(0, 0, 0)
print(apple)
#snake
snake = turtle
snake.penup()
snake.setup(width=1000, height=1000, startx=0, starty=0)
snake.shape("square")
snake.turtlesize(stretch_wid=3, stretch_len=3, outline=3)
snake.tracer(n=1, delay=0)
snake.setpos(260, 65)
snake.seth(180)
print(fruit)
for q in range(0, 3):
    snake.forward(65)
    snake.stamp()
def go():
    while snake.pos() != fruit:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('w' or 'W'):
            snake.seth(90)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a' or 'A'):
            snake.seth(180)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('s' or 'S'):
            snake.seth(270)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('d' or 'D'):
            snake.seth(0)
        snake.forward(65)
        snake.stamp()
        snake.clearstamps(1)
        print(snake.pos() == fruit)
go()
snake.exitonclick()
```

Comment: The if statements in the while loop should be replaced with elifs. You can make your code far easier to read by creating `x` and `y` using a loop, or, even better, using some math. I also don’t see the purpose of the `go()` function.

Comment: The `for p in range(0,3):` loop should be written `for _ in range(3):`, since `p` seems unused and the default start value for `range()` is 0. Same thing for the `for q in range(0, 3):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independent of turtles, comparing two floating point numbers with `==` is a losing strategy.  Though *very* similar, they aren't necessarily `==`.

This is true of turtles which wander a floating point plane -- they may never come back to the exact same position they occupied earlier.  The solution is to use the `distance()` method and compare the result to the amount of *slop* you're willing to accept in the comparison.

Here's a rework and simplification of your code along these lines:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randrange

def go():
    snake.forward(60)

    if snake.distance(apple) < 45:
        apple.hideturtle()
        x, y = randrange(-330, 330, 60), randrange(-300, 300, 60)
        apple.goto(x, y)
        apple.showturtle()

    screen.ontimer(go, 500)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=720, height=720, startx=0, starty=0)

apple = Turtle()
apple.hideturtle()
apple.shape('square')
apple.turtlesize(3)
apple.color('red')
apple.penup()

x, y = randrange(-330, 330, 60), randrange(-330, 330, 60)
apple.goto(x, y)
apple.showturtle()

snake = Turtle()
snake.shape('square')
snake.turtlesize(3)
snake.penup()

screen.onkey(lambda: snake.seth(90), 'w')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.seth(90), 'W')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.seth(180), 'a')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.seth(180), 'A')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.seth(270), 's')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.seth(270), 'S')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.seth(0), 'd')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.seth(0), 'D')

screen.listen()

go()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to look for if the snake was nearby to the apple. I was trying to look for when the snake was exactly on the apple.